# Как одним SQL запросом получить имена юзеров которые купили 3 и более разных товаров?

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеются 3 таблицы:

```
goods (поля: id, model); 
users (поля: id, name);
purchases (поля: id, user_id, good_id);
```

как одним запросом получить имена юзеров которые купили 3 и более разных товаров?

P.S. товары хранятся в goods; покупки в purchases

Comment: JOIN таблиц. Группировка по юзеру. Подсчёт уникальных товаров. Отбор по заданному количеству.

Comment: А это вообще можно одним запросом сделать?

Comment: Да, всё вышеописанное прекрасно помещается в один запрос.

Comment: Можете написать код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так как то

```
SELECT 
     users.id, -- на случай если имя одинаково
     users.name     
FROM 
    users
    INNER JOIN purchases
      ON purchases.user_id = users.id         
GROUP BY 
    users.id, 
    users.name
HAVING
   count(purchases.good_id) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел небольшую неточность в предыдущем решении нужно чтобы считались РАЗНЫЕ товары

```
SELECT 
     users.id, 
     users.name     
FROM 
    users
    INNER JOIN purchases
      ON purchases.user_id = users.id         
GROUP BY 
    users.id, 
    users.name
HAVING
   count(distinct(purchases.good_id)) >= 3
```